# Pause all Vimeo videos with API?

Tags: vimeo, froogaloop

I have hit a wall and cannot figure out how to make this work. With Vimeo's Advanced API I am pulling in all videos from an account with thumbnails. When clicking on a thumbnail the video is shown above and clicking on a different thumbnail hides the currently shown video. The problem is that the video continues to play even when it is hidden. I have spent a few hours looking at the API and I cannot get it to pause when hidden.

```
var iframe = $('.video')[0];

  $('.thumbnail a').click(function(e) {

  $f(iframe).api('pause');

  });
```

The above code pauses only the first video. If I change the number [0] to [1], then the second video pauses when you click on another thumbnail. Does anyone have any thoughts? I am using froogaloop in the above code.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this code to pause all YouTube and Vimeo videos on the page:

```
$('iframe').each(function() {
  this.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*');
  this.contentWindow.postMessage('{"method":"pause","value":""}', '*');
});
```

Comment: I love you <3 Like a charm!

Answer (score 5):

I used this with jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://a.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function pauseAll() {
    $('iframe[src*="vimeo.com"]').each(function () {
        $f(this).api('pause');
    });
}
// ]]></script>
```

use it on an onclick.

```
<a href="#" onclick="pauseAll(); return false;">pause all</a>
```